# Is there a way to get only portions of the data from a document through a REST Api call

Tags: rest, xpages

I’m working on an application with documents containing 150+ fields.

This is an HTML5 app that uses Domino / XPages / ExtLib as a data service mechanism.

In most cases, when performing REST calls, I only need to work on small fragment of the document.

I’m looking for a way to create RESt get call to receive predefined portions of the documents.

If data is changed on the client side I know I can update on a field by field basis with a Http Patch call.

Redisign of the back-end app is not an option at the time.

Comment: Do you use Domino Data Service for your REST calls?

Comment: To be honest, I'm in the starting phase and have not decided yet. I'm pragmatic about this, if the XPages components is what it takes, that will be my choice. I have full control of the back end application

Comment: So adding XPages code is an option? I misunderstood your "redesign of the backend app is not an option" then.

Comment: Yes, I can see that it could be misunderstood. The format of the notes document cannot be changed ( to much work on redesign) . That is why I want to read only portions of the document on my Ajax calls.
I’m happy to extend the back end application with some XPages to achieve my goals

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the extension Library's rest service control.

http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xe_restService.html

It will allow you to build an xpage on top of the existing app that can interact with the db with all the functionality you want without redesigning anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree to get all the document's data and filter it client side instead of trying to build your own REST service. A wonderful guide to working with REST calls in both ways reading and writing data to a document can be found here: http://www.assono.de/blog/d6plinks/REST-Services-with-the-XPages-Extension-Library

Answer (score 0):

Since redesing back-end app is not an option, you may either build your own REST service on top of the existing backend. Your REST service would then filter the unwanted field.

If building your own REST service is costly in time, efforts... what ever, consider filtering the data with many fields on client side.